# Parse.com: Sort by number of comments

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform, relation

I'm creating a UITableView with posts. If one of the tableview's rows is tapped, a detail page is shown where comments can be made to the post. I'm using the Parse.com framework to realize this.

I save the comments like this in the detailview:

```
PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
comment[@"content"] = _textViewComment.text;
comment[@"post"] = _object;
comment[@"user"] = currentUser;

[comment saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        UIAlertView* alertSave = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Saved" message:@"Your comment is saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertSave show];
        [self setToDefault:_textViewComment];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Comment not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

where _object is the current post.

What I want to do now is sort the first tableview by number of comments. But I'm only making a relation from the comment to the post and not the other way around.

Is there a way to query the posts and sort them by number of comments?

Comment: Can you post the code where you query the post (_object) ?

Comment: I query it in the first view controller where the tableview is:

    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [postQuery includeKey:@"author"];
    [postQuery orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
    [postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callBack:)];

then the callback:
- (void)callBack:(NSArray*)array{
    memoires = array;
    [tableViewMemoires reloadData];
}

then I pass it to the next view controller with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should relate comments to posts via an array on Post.

Add a "comments" col of type array on Post.  When you fetch the post, use `includeKey`: on the @"comments" key.  Then change your update code to add a comment like this...

```
// in your code, I think "_object" is a post. calling it "post" here instead...

NSMutableArray *comments = [[post objectForKey:@"comments"] mutableCopy];
[comments addObject:comment];
[post setObject:comments forKey:@comments"];

// then save the post object.  parse will save the related comment.
[post saveInBackgroundWithBlock ...
```

Double check everything in the data browser.  Then, after the next fetch of posts, you can sort by comment count...

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSComparator comparator = ^(Post *postA, Post *postB) {
            NSNumber *countA = @([postA objectForKey:@"comments"].count);
            NSNumber *countB = @([postB objectForKey:@"comments"].count);
            return [countA compare:countB];
        };
        NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparator];
        // use sortedArray as your tableview datasource
    }
}];
```

Comment: When I do this, saveInBackGroundWithBlock isn't called anymore

Comment: It must be getting called with an error, can you set a breakpoint before you check for error?